# Is it possible to back up a Docker container with all the volumes / data / state?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and was wondering if it was possible to set the following up:

I have my personal computer on which I'm working on my WordPress site via a Dockerfile. All his well and the data is persistent.

What I'd like to do is be able to save that work on Docker hub possibly or Github (I assume the updated images would be backed up on my Docker hub) and work on a totally different computer picking up where I left off.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should be able to set up your Docker containers such that there is no persistent state inside the container at all; you can freely delete and recreate the container without losing data.  The best and easiest case of this is a container that just depends on some external database, in which case you don’t need to do anything.

If you have something like a Wordpress installation with local customizations, or something that stores persistent data in the filesystem, you should use the `docker run -v` option or the Docker Compose `volumes:` option to inject parts of the host filesystem into the container.  Then those volumes need to be backed up (and for all that the Docker documentation endorses named volumes, if you use host directories, your normal backup solution will work fine.

In short, I’d recommend:

- **Build a custom image** for your application, and check the Dockerfile and any supporting artifacts into source control.  They don’t need to be separately backed up; even if you lose your image you can `docker build` again.
- **Inject customizations using bind mounts**, and check those customizations into source control.  They don’t need to be separately backed up.
- **Store mutable data using volumes or bind mounts**, and back these up normally.
- **Containers are disposable.** You don’t need to back up a container *per se*, you should always be able to recreate it from the artifacts above.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense and it's the direction I was heading to. Technically, I only really need to backup my `wp-content` directory along my `docker-compose.yml` file I assume.